# SharePoint 2010 difference with lookup columns

Tags: sharepoint-designer, upgrade, lookup-column

I recently upgraded my site from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010.
The first issue I noticed was that the "lookup" columns in "Display view" showed up as the hyperlink instead of the string.

```
Salesman "<a onclick="OpenPopUpPage('http://sharepoint2010:72/blackbook/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={FB9575AE-F747-49F1-9122-D15D095C7D0A}&ID=1&RootFolder=*', RefreshPage); return false;" href="[http://sharepoint2010:72/blackbook/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={FB9575AE-F747-49F1-9122-D15D095C7D0A}&ID=1&RootFolder=*">RRH</a>
```

I fixed it in SharePoint Designer by right clicking on it and "Format Item as... Label". Afterwards my string shows up, but as a hyperlink.

`Salesman RRH` -> RRH is a hyperlink

The problem is that I have a javascript pushing values of 8 of my columns to a "New Item".
All of the "text" and "number" columns work just as they did in SP2007, but the "Lookup" columns send the hyperlink.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

1- one solution is to use XPath functions to extract the simple inner text. see below sample

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before( substring-after(@Service_, '&gt;') , '&lt;') "/>
```

you can use some useful auto-complete XPath editor or more advanced editor in ribbon (see below image)

[image]

2-   note the **disable-output-escaping="yes"** attribute which essentially disable escaping of final tag attribute which leads to seeing

```
<xsl:value-of  disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Vendor_"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this URL

This may help u

http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Using-the-SharePoint-2010-Modal-Dialog.aspx